# Edgeworth Box (Non-Convex preference)

Tags: microeconomics, general-equilibrium, pareto-efficiency, competitive-equilibrium, edgeworth-box

Consider a situation that agent A's indifference curves are concave, while B’s indifference curves are convex and both sets of indifference curves have exactly the same shape. A northeast movement increases A’s utility but decreases B’s utility.

I know U(x,y)= min(x,y) and U(x,y)= max{x,y} represent this case. But is there any other combination of utility functions that also represents that situation? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

If total endowments are $(\bar x,\bar y)$ and $A$ has utility function $u_A(x_A,y_A)$, then $B$'s utility function $u_B(x_B,y_B)\equiv -u_A(\bar x-x_B,\bar y-y_B)$ has the same indifference curves as $A$'s.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But could you provide an example to show this?

Comment: This construction does not satisfy the condition that a movement in the northeast direction increases A's utility but decreases B's utility.  The following correction will do the job: $u_B(x_B, y_B) = -u_A(\overline{x}-x_B, \overline{y}-y_B)$

Comment: @Amit, that's right, sorry. Now corrected.

Comment: @KKecon, just use e.g. $u_A(x_A,y_A)=x^2_A+y^2_A$ with $(\bar x,\bar y)=(5,5)$ and substitute.

Comment: Thanks. So, for agent B' utility function, is it equal to $u_B(x_B, y_B) = - (\overline{x}-x_B)^2 - (\overline{y}-y_B)^2$ ?

Comment: @KKecon, yes. In this example you get $u_B(x_B,y_B)=10(x_B+y_B)-(x^2_B+y^2_B)-50$, but you can further simplify by discarding the constant.